# how to convert file which consist of numbers into a list in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, matrix

i have a text file which consist of 4*4 matrix separated by tab space and only 0,1. i want to check every array is surrounded by how many ones. both vertical and horizontals. is there a way to assign true for 1 and false for 0 and separate each array so we can put it in  a for loop?

the text file looks like this:

```
                                  1   0   1  1
                                  1   0   0  1
                                  0   0   1  1
                                  1   1   0  1
```

and i want the output to look like this:

```
                                  1   3    2   2
                                  1   4    5   4
                                  3   4    4   5
                                  1   2    4   2
```

i tried to make a dictionary and assign true or false values for zero and one but couldn't.

Comment: The required output makes no sense. Why would the third row end with 5? Surely it should be 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you would use a dictionary for this.

Just open the file and read (at most) four lines. Tokenise each line. Convert each token (assumed to be either '0' or '1') to int and build a 4x4 list.

Then you just need a function to check the 'cells' adjacent to any given coordinate.

Something like this:

```
FILENAME = '/Volumes/G-Drive/matrix.txt'

MAP = [
    (-1, -1),
    (-1, 0),
    (-1, 1),
    (0, -1),
    (0, 1),
    (1, -1),
    (1, 0),
    (1, 1)
]

def count_adjacent(r, c, lst):
    rv = 0
    for x, y in MAP:
        if (_r := r + x) >= 0 and _r < 4 and (_c := c + y) >= 0 and _c < 4:
            rv += lst[_r][_c]
    return rv

with open(FILENAME) as mdata:
    lst_in, lst_out = [], []
    for row in range(4):
        tokens = mdata.readline().split()
        lst_in.append([int(t) for t in tokens])
    for r in range(4):
        lst_out.append([])
        for c in range(4):
            lst_out[r].append(count_adjacent(r, c, lst_in))
    for row in lst_out:
        print(*row)
```

**Output:**

```
1 3 2 2
1 4 5 4
3 4 4 3
1 2 4 2
```

Note that the value in lst_out[2][3] is 3 and not 5 as per OP's question. I believe 5 would be incorrect given the problem statement